# Input field gets hidden along with whole div element when clicked into it

Tags: php, css, forms, user-input, pointer-events

I have a php table retrieved dynamically from Mysql, and i also have an input field in the table to edit a column.

When i clicked anywhere on the table, the table would disappear - so i used  pointer-events: none; in the css. This cured the problem, however now when i click the input field to type something in, the table disappears again.

I do not want the table to disappear when i click on the input field to type something in.

I have tried many different Pointer events in the css of the input field without any luck...and if i take the pointer-events: auto; out of the css for the input field, i cannot click on the input field at all

Below is my code - Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Code for my Table:

```
<div id="table1" class="table1">    
<form action="" method="post">
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$searchTerm=$_POST['search']; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare(" SELECT question.description AS question, answer.description AS answer, discipline.name AS name, response.responseid AS responseid, response.response AS response, response.student_id AS student_id, response.Date_Time AS Date
        FROM response
        INNER JOIN answer ON response.question_id = answer.answerid
        INNER JOIN question ON response.question_id = question.qid
        INNER JOIN discipline ON response.discipline_id = discipline.disciplineid WHERE Date_Time LIKE :searchTerm");
$stmt->bindValue(':searchTerm','%'.$searchTerm.'%');
$stmt->execute();
$result=0;




    /*
The above code is a query which selects attributes according to the search term
*/



echo "<table> <tr><th>Discipline</th><th>Question</th><th>Student ID</th><th>Response</th><th>Date & Time</th><th>Answer</th><th>Final Marks</th></tr>";
while ($response = $stmt->fetch())    /* This is a While loop which iterates each row */
{

echo " <tr><td>".$response["name"]."</td><td>".$response["question"]."</td><td>".$response["student_id"]."</td><td>".$response["response"]."</td><td>".$response["Date"]."</td><td><input type='text' name='date' value=". $response["answer"]."></td></tr> "; 
    $result++;


}



}  /* This bit of code closes the connection with the database */
?>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
</form>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .table1 {
        position: fixed;
        pointer-events: none;
        background-color: white;   
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 40px;
        color: black;
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-top: 66px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
.table1 input {
    pointer-events: auto;
    width: 20px;
    height:25px;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of the HTML your PHP code outputs?

Comment: You missed the quotes of value attribute in the input tag.

Comment: @99tharun where do the quotes need to be? Sorry can't see where I am missing them

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I can add a screenshot tomorrow but  basically the output is a table that disappears when the mouse is clicked on the input field

Comment: @Chodri it should be `value='". $response["answer"]."'>`

Comment: @99tharun I will try this tomorrow and see how I get along. Thanks

Comment: @99tharun I have changed it and it hasn't made  a difference....